# Change property value of control if the control has the property

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, properties

Some controls on my form have a DataSource property on the control itself, some dont.

I want to loop through all the controls and set the DataSource to Nothing if the control has the property. It would work something like this.

```
Private Sub ClearAllDatabindings()
    If _dataBindingsSet = True Then
        For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
            ClearDataBindings(ctrl)
            SetDatasourceToNothing(ctrl) '-- This is the piece idk how to Write.
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

I am not sure how to check this during run-time.

Comment: Consider using Reflection. GetProperties

Comment: @TimFreese c# and vb.net are two sides of the same coin in winforms.

Comment: @Ian Im not very knowledgeable about reflection. Can you give a reference/example?

Comment: I only know in C#. Your code seems to be using VB. Will that be OK?

Comment: @Ian yes I use http://converter.telerik.com/ to switch between the two.

Comment: OK, I put up an answer for you. Please check. And if there is anything, I think Googling on System.Reflection on VB.Net could be of great help too. It has been pretty late past midnight in my timezone now. Have to sleep. May not be too responsive till morning in my timezone. Hope you solve your issue!

Comment: @Ian works great ty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested by OP, In C#, using System.Reflection, you could do something like this to check if a class / its instance has property or not:

```
//for class type
var props = typeof(MyClass).GetProperties();
if (props == null || props.Length <= 0) { //does not have property
     //do something
}

//for class instance
var props = classInstance.GetType().GetProperties();
if (props == null || props.Length <= 0) { //does not have property
     //do something
}
```

To check for specific property:

```
 var prop = props.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == "propName");
 if(prop != null){
     //has that property
     //do changing of your Control here
 }
```